# How to sort date parameters in iOS?

Tags: core-data, nsdate

I am fetching data from database(coredata)and trying to sorting dates(startDate).Initially  i am having date in form of epoch format(like 1427736600,1427736611,etc) , I am converting into NSDate format and trying to sort but i am getting crash in sorting process.I don’t know where I am doing mistake.Here is my code.thanks

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Sessions"];
fetchRequest.predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“element == %@", element];

NSArray *storedSessions = [appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

NSArray *sortedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

if (storedSessions.count>0)
{
for (Sessions * listData in storedSessions)
{
    double time=[listData.startDate doubleValue];

    NSDate *returnDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm aa"];
    NSString *dateStr1=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:returnDate];

    sortedArray = [storedSessions sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *dateStr1, NSString *obj2) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mma"];
        NSDate *date1 = [dateFormater dateFromString:dateStr1];
        NSDate *date2 = [dateFormater dateFromString:obj2];
        NSComparisonResult compareResult = [date1 compare:date2];
        switch (compareResult)
        {
            case NSOrderedAscending:
                return NSOrderedDescending;
                break;
            case NSOrderedDescending:
                return NSOrderedAscending;
                break;
            default:
                return compareResult;
                break;
        }
    }];

  }

NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard.

Take a look at `NSSortDescriptor`. Build one to sort by your integer field that's storing epoch seconds, and pass that along in your fetch request. You'll get back an array sorted by the epoch seconds, ascending or descending, as you prefer.

And, you're working too hard. You can store `NSDate` directly into Core Data, as an attribute of type `Date`.